# curl_getinfo return nothing. and take 30 sec to load

Tags: php, redirect, curl

Recently a piece of simple code that worked stopped working.
the code is basicly fetching the page source, I was using file_get_contents('www.urlOfThePageIwantToLoad.com');
For some reason it now take forever to load and return false

So I decided to go with curl to get more information for debugging.

So I make the request like the following

```
function curl_get_file_contents($URL)
{
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    $contents = curl_exec($c);
    print_r(curl_getinfo($c));
    print_r(curl_error($c));
    curl_close($c);

    if ($contents) return $contents;
    else return FALSE;
}
```

Now this also take like 30 sec to load.
Then curl_getinfo() print me the following.

```
Array
(
 [url] => HTTP://www.urlOfThePageIwantToLoad.com/
 [content_type] => 
 [http_code] => 0
 [header_size] => 0
 [request_size] => 0
 [filetime] => -1
 [ssl_verify_result] => 0
 [redirect_count] => 0
 [total_time] => 20.172
 [namelookup_time] => 0.016
 [connect_time] => 0
 [pretransfer_time] => 0
 [size_upload] => 0
 [size_download] => 0
 [speed_download] => 0
 [speed_upload] => 0
 [download_content_length] => -1
 [upload_content_length] => -1
 [starttransfer_time] => 0
 [redirect_time] => 0
 [certinfo] => Array
     (
     )
 [redirect_url] => 
)
```

And `curl_error()` is giving me this

`Failed connect to www.urlOfThePageIwantToLoad.com:80; No error`

What is happening ?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: probably a network error. you're not allowed to reach out like this from your server, a firewall is prevent it, blahb lah blah.

Comment: Hum, But the thing is that it work when I use google.com as url

Comment: fire up a shell, and try `traceroute www.urlofthepageiwantoload.com`, see if that host is even reachable. and even then, maybe everything's fine on your end. maybe that host has blacklisted your IP.

Comment: Try `telnet www.urlOfThePageIwantToLoad.com 80` from the machine running your script to see if you can access the site.

Comment: I like the ping/traceroute/telnet suggestions.  Could also increase your timeout just to see if it does eventually respond.  `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` and `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`

Comment: Thanks guys I did a tracert and its taking more than 30 hop and most of them give me request timed out.  I contacted my server provider and there are looking into this now.